# Unable to connect Oracle ODI Marketplace to mysql embedded repository

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

i'm starting using Oracle ODI Marketplace. I've just deployed an instance on a VM in Oracle Cloud, by choosing the solution with the embedded mysql repository.

Now the problem is that when i start executing ODI i'm not able to connect ODI studio to mysql repository because i don't know/find the credentials needed to connect.
I've read the documentation but it is not so detailed about that.
i would really appreciate if you could help me

Thank you

Comment: Hi, finally i found the solution. i have read the documentation better and the problem was that i was connected through VNC viewer with the wrong user, opc, instead of oracle user. By connecting with oracle user you have credentials for the embedded mysql repository already filled in, so you are able to connect directly to that repository.

Comment: Please provide your solution so that others can benefit from it.